# upgrading a feature from drupal 6 to drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, upgrade

I need to use features created by me on a drupal 6 website over a new drupal 7 instance. Is there a way to port drupal 6 features to drupal 7.Or will upgrading the website give me d7 version of the features..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading your site and then recreating the features will give you Drupal 7 versions of the features if Features 7.x-1.0-beta3 provides an upgrade path from Features 6.x-1.1.